# assigning io_service to work - boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I know I could assign io_service to work using the constructor as such

```
 boost::asio::io_service work(io_service);
```

My question is suppose my work object is a member method of a class. How can I assign it io_service in the constructor. Is there a method that could assist in doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);
```

because boost::asio::io_service is not copyable, you can do that in the constructor init list like normal:

```
Foo::Foo(boost::asio::io_service &io_service)
  : work_member(io_service) {
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks out of curiosity does it have a member method which could be used to attach io_service at a later stage ?

Comment: I don't think so, no. `boost::asio::io_service::work` only has a copy ctor and one taking an `io_service` object, so even building a work object without an io service is impossible. You could, of course, use a `std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>` and make the work object at a later time.